# Routes chaining in express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a simple app, built with the help of node.js and express. This app has multiple routes and basic login/logout mechanics. I want all routes to redirect to a login form if the user is NOT logged in. This can be done by inserting auth checker lines into each route file.

**The question is :**
Is it possible to chain the routes to push all requests through login checker route and then pass it to the requested one without writing anything to existing route files?

E.g. existing routes are  "/", "/upload", "/login", "/logout".
I want the request to **get** or **post** "/upload" to be first processed by "/login" route and then by "upload" route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can chain handlers in a route. Your handler definition should be like

```
routehandler(req, res, next){
   //send response directly
   //or call next to call the next handler
}
```

You can then put multiple handlers in the order you want:

```
app.get('/server', ensureAuthenticated, housekeeping, routes.server.get)
```

Here `ensureAuthenticated` and `housekeeping` dont send the response just call `next()`. The last one returns the resulting page.

Please see you would want a different handler than what you use for login. Login page would do authentication, rest pages should just check if the user is authenticated or not. The difference would be clear if you are using sessions.

---

The args for the route handlers are the same as that of middlewares. Those are :

1. (err, req, res, next) Error handlers
2. (req, res, next) Non-error handlers

A trivial variation of above is that `next` can be left out if it is the end function you want in callback chain. You cannot have other args apart from these. You can see the how they are called [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js) (line 154).

A route consists of method, route-match and callback array. Like the middlewares the callback chain is executed sequentially for a specific route until response is returned or error is thrown.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain, where routehandler gets its args (req, res, next, etc). I don`t pass them in any part of code. Can I call it as `routehandler(next,req,err,res)` ?